# Changing the format of created_at and updated_at in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel's migrations to create some database tables and I was wondering if it's possible for it to create `DATETIME` columns rather than `TIMESTAMP` ones. The code I'm using is below:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name', 255);
$table->bigInteger('size');
$table->dateTime('downloaded_at');
$table->timestamps();
```

I know I can change the format that dates come back using a property in my model, however I'd like them to be `DATETIME` in my database if possible.

Comment: Why do you prefer `DATETIME`?  I generally prefer `TIMESTAMP` because it is timezone-aware.

Comment: @eggyal, you've got that backwards; `DATETIME` includes timezone info, `TIMESTAMP` is always stored as UTC.

Comment: @BillKarwin: As far as I'm aware, `DATETIME` doesn't store any timezone info at all?  By saying that `TIMESTAMP` is "timezone-aware", I meant that it translates between the session `time_zone` (at the client-end) and UTC (for storage).

Comment: /me looks stuff up furiously... @eggyal, my bad, you're right. I retract my statement. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging in the source and the type of the time-stamps is hard-coded so you cannot just re-configure it to `DateTime`.

I think a better approach would be for you to create your own columns (not using timestamps())
and then in your model you can do this:

```
public class User extends Eloquent
{
      public function save()
      {
            $this->attributes['created_at'] = new DateTime;
            return  parent::save();
      }
}
```

Another approach would be to use [ModelObservers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers)

```
class UserObserver {

    public function saving($model)
    {
        //
    }
}

User::observe(new UserObserver);
```

and you can also possibly try overriding the `timestamp()` function of the `Blueprint` class, but there is no guarantee that this will not mess up Laravel somewhere else in the code, because it uses Carbon to handle dates etc ...

```
class MyBlueprint extends Blueprint
 {
        public function timestamp($column)
        {
                return $this->addColumn('dateTime', $column);
        }
 }
```

and then use MyBlueprint when defining your table structure for the migrations:

```
 Schema::create('users', function(MyBlueprint $table) {
    // code
    $this->timestamps();
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the timestamps provide a native way of updating those dates when a change is persisted. Replacing timestamps with new columns is quite easy, both in model and migration. Handling saves handled properly is another story : Save is used for both insert and update. In your example, the created_at attribute will be "updated" with each save, which is clearly not what anybody would want. And you might not want to have updated_at updated if no change was caused (properties set with original values)

Comment: The Model events look like a promising solution but it should be noted that events are not fired in mass assignments (When using the create or update methods.)